# Finding the distance to the coordinate beginning in Poisson process. $R^3$

Tags: poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I have a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$, the distances from the coordinate beginning are $\gamma_1, \gamma_2,...\gamma_n$ and I am to find the density function of the variable $\gamma_n$.

I have done a problem, that has similarities. The problem was finding the distance to the nearest point. With this, I am having trouble, producing anything tangible. Thoughts?

Comment: Would you mind explaining what ‘coordinate beginning’ refers to?

Comment: The point $(0,0,0)$. Thats all i know

Comment: I see, so it means the origin. Also, are $\gamma_n$’s arranged in increasing order? If this is true, here is a hint: If $N(D_r)$ denotes the number of Poisson points in the closed ball $D_r\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ of radius $r$ centered at the origin, we have $\mathbb{P}(\gamma_n \leq r) = \mathbb{P}(N(D_r)\geq n)$.